# Are there any sources for a story about an angel coming down and healing people at a pool?

Tags: sources-mekorot, medicine, malach-angel

The Christians have a story about an angel coming down to a pool (at Bethesda) and dispensing healing.  (It sounds like they were anticipating this event.)  Are there any Jewish sources for this story?

Comment: off topic. I suggest deletion

Comment: Why would you (or anyone) suspect that there would be a Jewish source for this story? Please [edit].

Comment: Maybe because the source of Christianity is Judaism?

Answer (score 3):

I found a reference by google but it seems to say that there is no reference by any talmudic sources at all. The only reference given is to Josephus. I did not find any **Jewish** references to it in google.

[Pool of Bethesda](http://www.generationword.com/jerusalem101/51-bethesda-pool.html)

> The area of the Pools of Bethesda has always had a source of water. In
>   the days of the Old Testament, the area was outside the city of
>   Jerusalem to the north. It had a large pool that shepherds used and
>   was called the Sheep Pool. The gate on the north side of Jerusalem was
>   thus called the Sheep Gate. In the 700’s BC a dam was built to turn
>   the spring into a reservoir that would collect rain water which could
>   then be channeled into the city. The area was associated with sheep,
>   sacrifice, and the Temple because of its proximity to the Temple.
>
> The Hasmoneans added a second pool on the south side of the dam and
>   covered the channel to improve water quality. This site was uncovered
>   in 1888 by K. Schick, but it had been known about since the days of
>   the Byzantines and Crusaders, as evidenced by the remains of the
>   church that was built over it. **No ancient Jewish writers refer to this
>   pool, although Josephus did write of the Pool of the Sheep-market**.
>   Some early Christian writers recorded a spring of water here that
>   flowed with a red, ruddy color that some people have tried to
>   associate with the blood of the Temple sacrifices. The spring that
>   feeds the pools has been located, and water still collects in the
>   lower areas.

Comment: @ Sabbahillel  Thanx

Comment: ....did Josephus reference the pool, or the purported miracle there?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu The implication of the quote is that he referred to the pool. Based on what I remember of Josephus, any actual references to the other religion were forged much later by a monk.

Comment: Josephus was Jewish

Comment: @JJLL He is generally regarded as an ancient Roman source rather than a "Jewish" source. While I might have expressed it differently, the quote was as given. My reference to the comment was that no Jewish source was discovered by google as the only quote that I found (which was the one mentioning Josephus)  seems to be a non-Jewish source.

Comment: The Mishnah in Zavim 1:5 mentions Gad-Yav (Greek God of Fortune) which could be the pool connected to the spring Siloah (https://halakhah.com/pdf/taharoth/Zavim.pdf)